# wrap component with span or div tag based on logic in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

what is the best way for me to use logic to wrap the component? I would like to have another `span` to wrap `Child` component if showSpan is true, maybe something like following, but it does not work

```
const Child = () => {
  return <button>click me</button>;
};
const Home = (props: { showSpan: boolean }) => {
  const { showSpan } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      {showSpan && (<span> ssss)}
        <Child />
        {showSpan && (</span>)}
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <Home showSpan={false} />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Fragment (empty tag) to be the alternative to span and use them as wrapper. Should work like this:

```
const Child = () => {
  return <button>click me</button>;
};

const Home = (props: { showSpan: boolean }) => {
  const { showSpan } = props;

  const Wrapper = showSpan ?
      ({children}) => <span>ssss {children}</span> :
      ({children}) => <>{children}</>;

  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <Child />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <Home showSpan={false} />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```